# Design and software-design tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-merge

Currently, both [design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) (1395 questions) and [software-design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-design) (79 questions) are tags on the site. Although there may be an extremely minuscule use case for the latter, the questions tagged with it all fall under the former. Merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the tag wiki for "design" explicitly states "software design"...consider it done.